# pytest causes asyncio loop to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

So running pytest on just any file with loop in it gives the error

```
test_post.py:6: in <module>
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:678: in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:584: in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
E   RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

The code is as follows...

```
import pytest
#from handlers import request_handler
import json

import asyncio
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
async def compute(x, y):
  print("Compute %s + %s ..." % (x, y))
  await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
  return x + y

async def print_sum(x, y):
  result = await compute(x, y)
  print("%s + %s = %s" % (x, y, result))
loop.run_until_complete( print_sum(1, 2) )
loop.close()
```

These are not the actual tests I want to write but I need the loop to work first... any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `__main__` entry point and put `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` beneath that.